# InAppWebView within LayoutBuilder fullscreen issue

Tags: flutter, flutter-layoutbuilder

I'm trying to use InAppWebView (v6 latest beta because I'm trying to get this to work on the web platform) to display an embedded vimeo player. In a new flutter app, this works fine:

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final GlobalKey webViewKey = GlobalKey();

    InAppWebViewSettings settings = InAppWebViewSettings(
        useShouldOverrideUrlLoading: true,
        mediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture: false,
        allowsInlineMediaPlayback: true,
        iframeAllowFullscreen: true);

    return Scaffold(
      body: InAppWebView(
          key: webViewKey,
          initialSettings: settings,
          initialUrlRequest: URLRequest(
              url: WebUri(Uri.dataFromString(
                      '<html><div style="position:relative;padding-top:56.25%;"><iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/689902544?h=1c8590a277" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; fullscreen; picture-in-picture" style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;width:100%;height:100%; allowfullscreen></iframe><p><a href="https://vimeo.com/689902544">Eternal Spring</a> from <a href="https://vimeo.com/christopherdormoy">Christopher Dormoy</a> on <a href="https://vimeo.com">Vimeo</a>.</p></div></html>',
                      mimeType: 'text/html')
                  .toString())
              //url: WebUri("https://orf.at")
              )),
    );
  }
}
```

When I click on the fullscreen icon in the Vimeo player, my browser correctly switches to fullscreen.

However, in my actual application, my widget is wrapped inside a LayoutBuilder and it seems, whenever the `InAppWebView` enters fullscreen, the `LayoutBuilder` triggers a rebuild of the child widget tree and thus immediately I'm thrown out of the fullscreen again.

What can I do to make fullscreen work also within a `LayoutBuilder`?

Comment: I would suggest you to wrap your  `InAppWebView` widget inside a `StatefulBuilder`. So when the constraints change (Full screen mode enabled), only the child widgets of the `StatefulBuilder` would change. not its parent widget (LayoutBuilder).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be in your usage of the `GlobalKey` - it's created every time `build` function is called
This, in turn causes re-initialization of the  `InAppWebView`, which will probably cause it to exit full-screen.

Simple solution is to create the `GlobalKey` once (or just completely omit it if you don't need it for anything else):

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final webViewKey = GlobalKey();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     ...
  }
}
```